# Regex needed to match a proper currency format of whole numbers, and set maximum dollar value

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex that enforces:

1. whole numbers only, no decimals/fractions
2. thousands separated by commas
3. sets a maximum value allowed. Acceptable range of 1-25,000,000,000   (25 billion)

I created the following regex that already accomplishes the first 2 requirements, only allowing acceptable values like:
1
1,000
25,000
250,000,000 etc.

but it's the 3rd requirement of setting a maximum value of 25 billion that I'm struggling with.

Does anyone know a way to enhance this current pattern to only allow values between the range of 1 - 25,000,000,000 ?

```
^[1-9]\d?\d?$|^(?!0,)(?!0\d,)(?!0\d\d,)(\d\d?\d?,)+\d{3}$
```

I did a lot of searching, and I found a regex that could impose a maximum value, but I can't quite figure out how to modify it to what I need to meet all 3 requirements. This is the one I found:

```
^((25000000000)|(2[0-4][0-9]{9})|(1[0-9]{10})|([1-9][0-9]{9})|([1-9][0-9]{8})|([1-9][0-9]{7})|([1-9][0-9]{6})|([1-9][0-9]{5})|([1-9][0-9]{4})|([1-9][0-9]{3})|([1-9][0-9]{2})|([1-9][0-9]{1})|([1-9]))$
```

Comment: a regex is not a great tool to do this. You *could* but it is easier to combine a regex to validate a pattern and the overlying programming environment to validate max and min ranges. What is the environment you are running the regex in?

Comment: Besides agreeing with @dawg, do you **need to** make sure it's a valid number, or just help the user avoid entering something by mistake? Just like emails, you can have a basic regex just to avoid typos, invalid characters as a first check (like check valid characters and length), but once it passes it, do a final check with code instead of a regex.

Comment: Hi @dawg, I realize that, but in my current scenario I need to enforce it via a regex due to how it'll be implemented and used. Thanks for the suggestion anyway. If it were any other scenario, I'd go that route, but I can't.

Comment: @Andrew - I need to ensure it's a valid whole number AND help the user avoid entering something by mistake, like a dollar value that exceeds what is set as a cap.

Comment: BTW, your regex validates `999,99,999` and `9,9,9,9,999`.

Comment: I just edited my post and added onto it another pattern that could help with the last requirement, but I'm not sure how to combine them to achieve all 3 requirements. I'm a bit new to regex patterns.

Comment: @Andrew LOL wow nice catch. Like I said, I'm a noob. :)

Comment: You can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
^([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3}){0,2})$|^(([1-9]|1\d|2[1-4])(,\d{3}){3})$|^25(,000){3}$
```

This regex consist of 3 main blocks or conditions:

1. `[1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3}){0,2}`: Any `1-9` followed by up to 2 digits, followed by up to 2 optional blocks of 3 digits preceded with a comma (supports up to `999,999,999`).
2. `([1-9]|1\d|2[1-4])(,\d{3}){3}`: Three possible billion values: `1-9`, or a `1` followed by any digit (to support `10-19`), or a `2` followed by a `1-4` digit (to support `20-24`). Then followed by 3 blocks of comma and 3 digits (supports up to `24,999,999,999`).
3. `25(,000){3}`: Finally, special case, support for `25,000,000,000`.

It matches:

```
1
12
123
1,000
25,000
250,000
2,500,000
24,999,999
25,000,000
250,000,000
1,500,000,000
2,500,000,000
15,000,000,000
24,999,999,999
25,000,000,000
```

And does **not** match:

```
0
1234
0,000
0,000,999
0,999,999,999
25,000,000,001
99,999,999,999
250,000,000,000
25,000,000,000,000
99,99,999
9,9,9,9,999
24999999999
25000000000
25000000001
26000000000
35000000000
```